# Double multiplication with brackets problem

Tags: c#

```
double celsius_0 = (100.5 - 32) * (5 / 9);
double celsius_1 = (100.5- 32) * 5 / 9;

Console.WriteLine(celsius_0);
Console.WriteLine(celsius_1);

output:
0
38,0555555555556
```

Why do they return differnt values?
I dont understand whats happening

Comment: In the first case, `(5/9)` is evaluated, as integer division, hence resulting in `0`

Comment: Please read [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)

Comment: If you really want to keep the brackets, change the number types for 5 and 9 from integers to doubles: `(5.0d / 9.0d)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because here `celsius_0 = (100.5 - 32) * (5 / 9)`
you count value in the first bracket then in the second one and then you multiply them.

While in the second line `(100.5- 32) * 5 / 9` you count value in bracket then multiply it by 5 and at the end divide it by 9

To sum up in mathematics first you do things in brackets and then multiply/divide and finally add/substract

Comment: The issue is actually due to type inference. The `(5 / 9)` is assumed to be an `int`, and `5/9` as an integer is indeed zero. Thus `100.5 - 32` multiplied by zero is zero. It's described more in depth in the duplicate answer.

Comment: This code works, because every operation is converted to `double` implicitly.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad guys. Didn't think about that